# 2D Bit matrix with every possible combination

Tags: python

I need to create a Python generator which yields every possible combination of a 2D bit matrix.
The length of each dimension is variable.

So for a 2x2 matrix:

1.
00
00

2.
10
00

3.
11
00

....

x.
00
01

Higher lengths of the dimentions (up to 200*1000) need to work too.
In the end, I will not need all of the combinations. I need only the ones where the sum in each line is 1. But I need all combinations where this is the case. I would filter them before yielding. Printing is not required.

I want to use this as filter masks to test all possible variations of a data set.
Generating variations like this must be a common problem. Maybe there is even a good library for Python?

Comment: For a 3X3 matrix will the values be 0,1,2 or you are operating on binary numbers ?

Comment: It is 0 and 1 only. Just all of the possible combinations.

Comment: It's unclear what's being asked here, is it the dot product or the cross product? No example of expected output is provided.

Answer (score 0):

You can generate every possibility of length 2 by using every number from 0 to 4(2 to the power of 2).

```
0 -> 00 
1 -> 01 
2 -> 10 
3 -> 11
```

For the displaying part of a number as binary, `bin` function can be used.

Since you have 2x2 matrix, you need 2 numbers(`i` and `j`), each for a row. Then you can just convert these numbers to binary and print them.

```
for i in range(4):
    for j in range(4):
        row1 = bin(i)[2:].zfill(2)
        row2 = bin(j)[2:].zfill(2)

        print row1, "\n" , row2, "\n"
```

**EDIT:**

I have found `zfill` function which fills a string with `zeros` to make it fixed length.

```
>>> '1'.zfill(5)
'00001'
```

---

Another generic solution might be:

```
import re

dim1 = 2
dim2 = 2
n = dim1 * dim2
i = 0 
limit = 2**n
while i < limit:
    print '\n'.join(re.findall('.'*dim2, bin(i)[2:].zfill(n))), '\n'
    i += 1
```

Comment: This solution works - but only with dimensions up to 5x5. Then range (also tried xrange) gets in trouble as the numbers get too big.

Comment: @Butuhan, you mean the "for i in range(2**n):" solution? That's what fails with a higher size of the dimensions.

Comment: I don't think there is a solution for that. for 5x5 matrix, there are 2**25 possibilities. Even just printing this much number takes too long.

Comment: In the end I will not need all of the combinations. I need only the once where the sum in each column is 1. But I need all combinations where this is the case. I would filter them before yielding. Printing is not required.

Comment: If you only need those with one bit set in each column, iterate over which position is set per column. The modulo operator may be helpful.

Comment: It indeed takes too long to generate all combinations. I need to limit it to generating only the combinations I really need. So all where the sum in all lines is == 1

Answer (score 0):

Going through all possible values of a bit vector of a given size is exactly what a counter does. It's not evident from your question what order you want, but it looks much like a Gray counter. Example:

```
from sys import stdout

w,h=2,2

for val in range(2**(w+h)):
    gray=val^(val>>1)
    for y in range(h):
        for x in range(w):
            stdout.write('1' if gray & (1<<(w*y+x)) else '0')
        stdout.write('\n')
    stdout.write('\n')
```

Note that the dimensions of the vector don't matter to the counter, only the size. Also, while this gives every static pattern, it does not cover all possible transitions.

Comment: This solution works - but only with dimentions up to 5x5. Then range (also tried xrange) gets in trouble as the numbers get too big.

Comment: That's a limitation of range, which uses a C long. If you use a Python long (just formulate the iteration as a while loop with increment) it'll work.

Comment: yes - works well with the while loop - but indeed not all combinations are in

Answer (score 0):

This can be done using permutation from itertools in the following way.

```
import itertools
dim=2
dimension = dim*dim
data = [0 for i in range(0,dimension)] + [1 for i in range(0,dimension)]
count = 1
for matrix in set(itertools.permutations(data,dimension)):
    print('\n',count,'.')
    for i in range(0,dimension,dim):
        print(' '.join(map(str,matrix[i:i+dim])))
    count+=1
```

P.S: This will be good for 2X2 matrix but a little bit time consuming and memory consuming for higher order. I would be glad if some one provides the less expensive algorithms for this.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But I need the dimentions to be unequal.

Answer (score 0):

you could do something like this for 3x3 binary matrix:

```
for i in range(pow(2,9)):
    p = '{0:09b}'.format(i)
    print(p)
    x = []
    x.append([p[0],p[1],p[2]])
    x.append([p[3],p[4],p[5]])
    x.append([p[6],p[7],p[8]])
    for i in range(3):
        x[i] = map(int, x[i])
```