# Find every possible permutation of bits in a 2D array that has a single group of contiguous 1s

Tags: algorithm, math, multidimensional-array, permutation, bitarray

Below I have represented 2 permutations of bits in a 2D bit array (1s are red). The matrix on the left has a single group of contiguous 1s but the right matrix has 2.

[image]        [image]

I would like to loop through every possible permutation of binary values in such an array that has a single group of contiguous 1s. I am aware that for a 10×7 grid like above there are 2<sup>(10 × 7)</sup> permutations when you include non-contiguous permutations, but my hope is that by excluding non-contiguous permutations I will be able to go through them all in reasonable CPU time.

Speaking of reasonableness, I am also interested in an algorithm to determine how many permutations are contiguous.

My question is similar to, but different from, these:

- [2D Bit matrix with every possible combination](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26777417/2d-bit-matrix-with-every-possible-combination)
- [Finding Contiguous Areas of Bits in 2D Bit Array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17978637/finding-contiguous-areas-of-bits-in-2d-bit-array)

Any help is appreciated. I'm a bit stuck.

Comment: How many rows and columns do you expect?

Comment: Even if you only look at the arrays with contiguous 1s I think the number is still too big for 10x7.

Comment: I agree that the number is still too big for 10x7. You should try an algorithm for smaller sizes, and see how it scales to see what a reasonable upper bound is for your problem. I have some ideas for an algorithm but it would best in a language like Python that has sets permutations and sets of frozen sets of permutations, and similar types. My ideas would still get a large amount of duplication, which would need testing to avoid adding duplicates.

Comment: I also doubt there is a reasonably simple algorithm to generate only contiguous  groups of 1s that doesn't work inside as "generate all and filter out non-contiguous" which totally beats the original goal of increasing speed.

Answer (score 0):

So, I found that the OEIS (Online Encyclopedia of Integer Sequences) has a sequence from `n = 0..7` for the "number of nonzero n X n binary arrays with all 1's connected" ([A059525](http://oeis.org/A059525)). They provide no formula though except for grids fixed at 1 cell wide ([triangular numbers](http://oeis.org/A000217)), or [2](http://oeis.org/A059020) or [3](http://oeis.org/A059021) cells wide. There's a [sequence for 4 x n](http://oeis.org/A059524) too but no formula.

Answer (score 0):

Two approaches I can think of.  One is to iterate through all possible sequences and devise a test for non-contiguous groups and some method for skipping over large regions guaranteed to be non-contiguous.

A second approach is to attempt to build all sets of contiguous groups so you don't need to test.  This is the approach I would take:

1. Let `n = width * height`
2. Enumerate blocks left to right, top to bottom from 0 to `n - 1`
3. Fix a block at position 0.
4. Generate all contiguous solutions between 1 and n blocks extending from position 0
5. Omit position 0 and fix a block at position 1
6. Find all contiguous solutions between 1 and `n - 1` blocks extending from position 1
7. Continue until you've reached position n

You can place your pieces according to the following rules, backtracking for the next placement at each depth:

1. To left of most recently placed piece if placed in row above prior piece provided that no other neighbors exist for that vacancy.
2. Above left-most available piece in row of most recently placed piece if no other neighbors exist for that vacancy.
3. To right of most recently placed piece (if adjacent piece exists)
4. On the next row, farthest left vacancy such that upper row has a piece above any contiguous right remaining neighbors
5. Next move for any backtracked position is first available move to the right of, or in the row below, the backtracked position (obeying prior 4 rules)